# Multiple ip on same interface in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, networking, ip

Is that possible to have multiple IPs on eth0 in a Docker container?

I would like having 5 IPs on eth0 in a Docker container interface. I am using "ip" utility. Executing `ip address add 172.20.0.200/16 dev eth0` in the container give "Operation not permited.

- I tried manually log to the container as root user using "sudo exec
  -u root ..".
- I have even tried apt-install sudo in the container. Result is same "Operation not permitted"

Comment: Usually Docker manages the network setup on its own and you don’t use tools like `ip` or `ifconfig`.  Why do you want multiple container-private IP addresses?

Comment: I would like to create a load test for my soft. The soft is build upon l2tp sockets over "ip" network. l2tp over "ip" does not use ports. Hence server binds only to IP. I know that I can run multiple containers but from perspective of tests it is not comfortable since these tests already has other tests. And I do not want write separate test where I have to aggregate output of each server from all containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. There must be added --cap-add option
`docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN image`

But as I understand docker know nothing about static IPs since `docker network inspect` shows only one IP. Hence think of using custom network